# Best way to check if record exists and use site wide

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to c# and MVC but I am building an intranet app. Being on the internal network there is no need to sign in to use the app but I do have it connected to a database which has an 'Administration' table. In this table are the administrator's email addresses. I am also using *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement* and then *UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress* to get the users email address. What I would like to do is compare the *UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress* to the database table and if there is a match then set a boolean to TRUE that I can reference/call upon within my entire site.

I have a model matching the database tables and I can also query the database using a where statement to the value of *UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress* but only within a set method (ActionResult) and return the boolean value within a viewbag to that particular controller that is accessed by the related view only.

I would like to know what is best practice for setting up my site so that whichever page a users visits their email is compaired to the database and a boolean is set to true/false if they are/aren't in the database administrator table.

Edit: Would this be to create a base controller and then inherit it in all other controllers and within the base controller perform the database query - if so a little guidance would be greatly appricated

My current set up is an EmailEntityModel:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class EmailEntities : DbContext
{
    public EmailEntities()
        : base("name=EmailEntities")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Audience> Audiences { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CallToAction> CallToActions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ColourScheme> ColourSchemes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EmailType> EmailTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Then I have an email Controller:

```
public class EmailsController : Controller
{
    private EmailEntities db = new EmailEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Emails.ToList());


    }
```

Can I use the EmailEntities to query the Administator DBset within my controller but can I use this elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to query the DB on every request and compare the current user's email against the admin email. If that's the case, then **you have many options**.

If it was me, I would keep the Admin email in a constant/static variable (so I don't have to make the trip to the DB on every request):

```
public static class StaticCache 
{
    // static constructor would run only once, the first it is used 
    // this value is maintained for the entire life-time of the application
    static StaticCache()
    {
        using (var context = MyApplicationDbContext.Create())
        {
            // get your admin email for the DB
            AdminEmail = context.Email.Where(/*some admin flag == true*/).FirstOrDefault(); 
        }
    }

    public static string AdminEmail;

    public static bool IsAdminUser(string curEmail)
    {
        return string.Equal(curEmail, AdminEmail, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

That's it. Now you can call `StaticCache.IsAminUser()` anywhere in your program (even in your view). All you need is to pass the current email to the method.

Comment: Thanks Hooman, in terms of adding this code, I assume this goes into my main controller, is that correct:
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Email_Comms.Models;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace Email_Comms.Controllers
{
 public class EmailsController : Controller
 { [Code go here]
  private EmailEntities db = new EmailEntities();
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
     return View(db.Emails.ToList());
  }`

Comment: No, this code should go into a separate file, called StaticCache.cs, then you can reference it from your controller or view.

Comment: that works great thanks. I have got it working passing static values but still trying to get it working with my database. I have updated the initial post to include the Enitiy model I am using and how I am referenceing this in my controller. Can this be used in the static Cache?

Comment: You can't keep changing the question as you make progress. If you need further assistance, please ask a new question. If the answer has solved your problem please mark it as accepted. This is how your question would be useful for the future readers. I am not going to keep updating my answer to fit your question.